# SQL convert no column name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following SQL Statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime), DisplayName
FROM     myTable
WHERE DisplayName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DisplayName asc
```

The two columns that get returned as `Display name` and `(No Column Name)` with the latter being a problem. I'm using this in an SSRS report and I need to pass my AuditDate value to it. With result now being `(No Column Name)` my report has missing information.

How can i fix this?

Comment: use an alias.. SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime) AS AuditDate, DisplayName

Comment: @Sean Hello, Did you solve the problem? Please accept the answer that was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Give your column an alias like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime) AS 'Audit Date'
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime) 'Audit Date'
```

depending on your preferred syntax

Comment: or just to show all syntaxes `SELECT DISTINCT 'Audit Date' = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime)`

Answer (score 2):

Just add [alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/alias.php) to result column

```
CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime) AS [AuditDate]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), AuditDate,113) AS datetime) AS AuditDate, 
    DisplayName
FROM     
    myTable
WHERE 
    DisplayName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    DisplayName ASC
```