# How to change the column name in a Blue Prism Collection?

Tags: blueprism

I am working with SQL Queries for a Blue Prism project, and in my queries I have to cast a few of the table columns for Blue Prism to accept them.

For example, instead of SELECT **[id]** FROM [tableName], I do SELECT **cast([id] as char(36))** FROM [tableName].

However, in my Blue Prism collection the column name now displays as "Column1" instead of "id" as I want it. In cases where I am not casting, the name shows up correctly.

How can I revert back to the name I want while still applying the casting?

Comment: try this: SELECT cast([id] as char(36)) as id FROM [tableName]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL convert no column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549289/sql-convert-no-column-name)

Answer (score 0):

1. The best way may be to set the column name in your query:

```sql
SELECT cast([id] as char(36)) AS cast_id FROM [tableName]
```

2. The another to use a code stage, with inDataTable, outDataTable parameters - where 
   outDatatable is made equal to inDataTable, and you set the column name as follows:

```vb
outDataTable.Columns(oldName).ColumnName = newColumnName
```

3. Collection Manipulation VBO should already have some code for renaming columns, too. E.g. "Rename Collection Fields".